# If there is no more than $k$ smooth rational curves on algebraic surface, what is the minimal value of k

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, rational-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth surface of general type with $q=p_g=0$, define a set $A=\{C\subset X|$ C is smooth rational and $C^2<-1\}$, let $k=|A|$ which is cardinality of $A$.

What is the minimal value of $k$ can be?

Can you give me some example of $X$ with $k\geq 0$, say $k=0,1,2,3,4,5\ldots$

Maybe what I am asking is some examples of surface of general type with very few smooth rational curves. Are there many of them?

Comment: Examples of *arbitrary* surfaces of general type with no rational curves on them (cf. your last question) are easy to come by. For example, products of curves of genus $\geq 2$, or more generally any surface that injects into its Albanese. However, the restriction $q = p_g = 0$ is quite severe, so it becomes a much more delicate question. (I'm not familiar enough with this area to produce an example where one can actually count the number of rational curves if $q = p_g = 0$, but I strongly suspect at least some examples are known.)

Comment: There are a wealth of surfaces of general type with $p_g=q=0$ which are of the form $(B\times C)/G$, where $B,C$ are smooth curves (of genus $\geq 2$) and $G$ is a finite group acting freely on $B\times C$. Such a surface contains no rational curves (a rational curve would lift to $B\times C$, which is clearly impossible).

Comment: It is worth noting that if your surface $X$ of general type is minimal, then regardless of the values of $q$ and $p_g$, the condition $C^2 < -1$ is automatic for any smooth rational curve $C$ on $X.$  Also, in light of abx's comment, you may want to impose topological conditions in addition to $q=p_{g}=0$, in order to get a better question.  (For instance, the standard Godeaux surface is minimal of the type you want, and it has smooth rational curves coming from the lines on the Fermat quintic surface; its fundamental group is $\mu_{5}.$)

Comment: @YusufMustopa Thanks very much for your comments, I did not quite understand your last sentence that the smooth rational curves coming from the lines on Fermat quintic surface, you mean all the smooth rational curves  on Godeaux surface are coming from the degree 1 curves on Fermat quintic surface?

Comment: @user41650 I don't know offhand if those are the *only* smooth rational curves on the standard Godeaux surface.  That said, I suspect numerical Godeaux surfaces (i.e. minimal surfaces of general type with $K^2=1$ and $q=p_{g}=0$) are at the very least a good place to start your inquiry.  A recent overview with good references is given in the introduction to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04621.pdf